# Estimates on gradients of diffusion semigroups

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider the Dirichlet or Neumann Laplacian on a manifold with boundary. Suppose we have some estimate of the form 
$$||e^{t\Delta} f||_{L^p} \leq C(t)||f||_{L^q}$$ for some $p, q$. For a specific example, let $p = \infty, q = 2$. My question is, if and when we can use estimates like the above to calculate estimates like
$$||\nabla e^{t\Delta} f||_{L^p} \leq C(t)||f||_{L^q}$$ for the same $p, q$.

PS: I have almost no background on probabilistic methods, so I would appreciate detailed references in that area (someone told me there are certain probabilistic methods of attack to these kinds of problems, that is why I have hesitatingly tagged probability as well). I am more or less okay with functional analysis/differential geometry/pde's.

Further edit: Internet search reveals that there is something called Bismut's formula which deals with something like this. Maybe, if that were translated in the semigroup language, it could lead to some kind of answer.

Comment: It seems unlikely, since clearly no such bound can hold as $t \to 0$ (consider a small but wiggly $f$).  However, estimates like $\| \nabla e^{t \Delta} f \|_p \le \|\nabla f\|_q$ have been studied - would that be of interest to you?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge I have edited the post. It was not clearly written, I wanted it to mean that the constant is dependent on $t$. The estimates that you mention are not of IMMEDIATE interest to me, but I would love to know about them as well. I will really appreciate some references on them.

Comment: So I think what you really want is an $L^r$ estimate on the gradient of the heat kernel.  Then your desired estimate follows from differentiating under the integral sign and using Holder's inequality.  There should be tons of work on estimating the gradient of the heat kernel; I don't have references off the top of my head but if you can't find any, I'll try to add something in the next couple days.